# How to achieve paginated UITableView like in this example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I am attaching an image. Some of you might have tried this iphone application before. It is a screen shot from Awesome Note. How do they achieve the 5 rows table view, with a swipe to next page for more rows?

Basically the **UITableView** (at least I think it's a TableView?) is confined to the bottom half of the **UIView**.

Any swipe to the left or right jumps to the next page and you see the next 5 rows (if any.) We can see from the screenshot that there are *at least* 11 rows, since it's 3 pages in depth.

Is this achieved using a TableViewController inside a UIScrollView or something? I've setup my own custom *TableViewController*, along with a *UITableView*. Inside interface builder when I check Attributes section for my UITableView I see an checkbox for **Paging Enabled**, which I've ticked.

I've also disabled Vertical Scrollers but this seems to have no effect? I'm obviously missing something, seeing as I haven't even seen where I can define how many rows / sections I'd like to render on one page before another page is created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: Awesome Note - Rows Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not a `UITableView`, thats a `UIScrollView` with custom buttons.

The Paging option is because UITableView is a sub-class of UIScrollView.

Comment: Very well, but you barely answered their question. Perhaps something a little more detailed than "custom buttons" might suffice.

Comment: Custom buttons is pretty self-explanitory.

Comment: ah. Thanks for this WrightsCS. I guess custom buttons actually does indeed make sense for that sort of view. Never thought of looking at it like that since I was dead set on that it must be a tableview.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 5 items, it's better to use 5 overlapping  UIButtons